# Using Caret CreateTimeSlices for Growing window prediction with Machine Learning Model

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, r-caret

I created a data set like this, the reason is I wanted to use a time series based data set

```
getSymbols("^GSPC")
DF=data.frame(GSPC,DATE=time(GSPC))
PriceChange=(DF$GSPC.Close-DF$GSPC.Open)
DF$Class<-as.factor(ifelse(PriceChange>0,"UP","DOWN")) 
DF$year = as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, format = "%Y"))
DF$MONTH = as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, format = "%m"))


GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume Class Year Month
1418.03   1429.42  1407.86    1416.60  3429160000   Down  2007   1
1416.60   1421.84  1408.43    1418.34  3004460000   Up    2007   1
```

Then I replaced the year by a number which can be added on to keep the month index (I guess there is a smarter way of doing this)

```
DF=data.table(DF)

DF[year==2007,year:=0]
DF[year==2008,year:=12]
DF[year==2009,year:=24]
DF[year==2010,year:=36]
DF[year==2011,year:=48]
DF[year==2012,year:=60]
DF[year==2013,year:=72]
DF[year==2014,year:=84]
DF[year==2015,year:=96]
DF[year==2016,year:=108]

DF$Month_Index=(DF$year+DF$MONTH)
```

so the data set has now the additional column

```
Month_Index
 01
 01

Month_Index=115
```

Then I used the `createTimeSlices` from `caret` to make a growing window prediction.

```
TimeSlices=createTimeSlices(1:Month_Index, 5, horizon = 2,
             fixedWindow = FALSE, skip = 0)


for(i in 1:nrow(DF))
{

  plsFitTime <- train(Class~.,
                      data = DF[TimeSlices$train[[i]],],
                      method = "pls")

  Prediction=predict(plsFitTime,DF[TimeSlices$test[[i]],])

}
```

Now I want to save predictions for each step and its proper index along with the accuracy. My question is how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to accomplish this:

```
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)
library(caret)

getSymbols("^GSPC")
DF <- data.frame(GSPC,DATE=time(GSPC))
PriceChange <- (DF$GSPC.Close-DF$GSPC.Open)
DF$Class <- as.factor(ifelse(PriceChange>0,"UP","DOWN"))
```

You can create Month indices in the following two ways:

```
# 1
DF$yearMon <- zoo::as.yearmon(DF$DATE)
DF <- data.table(DF)
DF[,  Month_Index:= .GRP, by = yearMon]

# 2
DF$year <- as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, format = "%Y"))
DF$MONTH <- as.numeric(format(DF$DATE, format = "%m"))
DF[, Month_Index2 := .GRP, by = .(year, MONTH)]

identical(DF$Month_Index, DF$Month_Index2)
[1] TRUE


Month_Index <- length(unique(DF$Month_Index))

TimeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:Month_Index, 5, horizon = 2,
                            fixedWindow = FALSE, skip = 0)
```

Create three empty lists to save your results:

```
totalSlices <- length(TimeSlices$train)

plsFitTime <- vector("list", totalSlices)
Prediction <- vector("list", totalSlices)
Accuracy   <- vector("list", totalSlices)
```

Save all the results to these lists:

```
k <- 1:totalSlices

for(i in seq_along(k))
{

    plsFitTime[[i]] <- train(Class~.,
                             data = DF[TimeSlices$train[[i]],],
                             method = "pls")

    Prediction[[i]] <- predict(plsFitTime[[i]], 
                              DF[TimeSlices$test[[i]],])

    Accuracy[[i]] <- confusionMatrix(Prediction[[i]], 
                                     DF[TimeSlices$test[[i]],]$Class)$overall[1]

}
```

All the models are saved in `plsFitTime`, predictions in `Prediction`, and accuracies in `Accuracy`.

**Update:**

A more **tidier** approach would be to use the `purrr` package.

After creating time slices, you can use:

```
library(purrr)

customFunction <- function(x, y) {
    model <- train(Class~.,
                   data = DF[x],
                   method = "pls")

    prediction <- predict(model, DF[y])

    accuracy <- confusionMatrix(prediction, 
                                DF[y]$Class)$overall[1]

    return(list(prediction, accuracy))
}

results <- map2_df(TimeSlices$train, TimeSlices$test, customFunction)
```

`map2_df` is a function that takes 2 lists `.x` and `.y` as the arguments, applies the function `.f` on all elements of those lists and returns the results as a dataframe.

You can create the function on the fly (just like `lapply`), but I created `customFunction` in the global environment just to keep the code clean.

`DF[x]` in the function is equivalent to `DF[TimeSlices$train[[n]]]` and `DF[y]` is `DF[TimeSlices$test[[n]]]`

`map2_df` now does everything that the `for` loop above did, and returns only the **predictions** and **accuracies** for all the models in the form of a dataframe.

```
class(results)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame" 

dim(results)
[1] 2 109
```

Each column in `results` is a list. 109 columns are the results from 109 models.

To access the result of each model (in this case prediction and accuracy) use `results$columnName` or `results[[columnNumber]]` .

If you want to store the models as well, just change the `return` statement in `customFunction` to include the model: `return(list(model, prediction, accuracy))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf) to gather your results using a list:

```
results <- plyr::llply(1:length(TimeSlices$train), function(i){
  plsFitTime <- train(Class~.,
                      data = DF[TimeSlices$train[[i]],],
                      method = "pls")

  testData <- DF[TimeSlices$test[[i]],]
  Prediction <- predict(plsFitTime, testData)

  list(index = i, model = plsFitTime, prediction = Prediction)
})

# The model created for slice no. 3
results[[3]]$model

# ... and it's predictions
results[[3]]$prediction
```

You can add accuracy inside the function passed to `llply` if you need it.